# How do I time shift a single audio clip in Audacity 2.0?

Tags: audacity

I want to move an audio clip so that it starts at a different time. I've read about this "time shift" tool, but am unable to figure out how to use it. The documentation was of no help to me. I can't find the "time shift" tool. I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The Time Shift tool is to the right of the playback & recording controls. Once it's selected, you can drag a clip simply by performing a standard drag-and-drop operation: click on the track, then - while holding down the mouse button - move the cursor to the right or the left.